# Creating new gpt header for broken SD-Card

Tags: partition, diskutil

I have a broken SD Card. It is detected by mac OS, but I cannot mount it or store data on it. When using `gpt -r show` and got this:

```
/dev/disk8 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.3 GB    disk8
```

The problem is that there is no gpt header, so no partinioning. Is there a way to recover the SD card?

Comment: What do you mean by broken?

Comment: What disk `fdisk` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preinstalled disk utility app from apple has a deleting function,w which does the job. However, it erased the data, but that was never a concern for me.